# PHP adding new values to an array in for loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop

Could you please someone show me the mistake I make that my code, which looks like so:

```
$arrayOfDays = array();
    for($dayIterator=$from; $dayIterator < $to; $dayIterator->modify('+1 day')){
        $arrayOfDays[] = $dayIterator;
    }
    print_r($arrayOfDays);
```

prints me such result:

```
Array ( [0] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [1] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [2] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [3] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [4] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [5] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [6] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [7] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [8] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [9] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [10] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [11] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [12] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [13] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [14] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [15] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [16] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [17] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [18] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [19] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [20] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [21] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [22] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [23] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [24] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [25] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [26] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [27] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [28] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) )
```

Where $from is set to the beginning of the month and $to to the end of the month.
When I print the $dayIterator inside the loop, it gives me the right date, but after finishing the whole array is filled with the last day!!
I have no idea why it is working like that :(

Comment: What do $from and $to values look like ?

Comment: Just a hint: PHP objects are passed by reference. So you save the reference to the object 30 times ;) You could solve it by saving a clone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try a different approach, something like [DatePeriod](http://php.net/dateperiod)

What you have to provide is a:

- Start/End DateTime objects, and DateInterval object.

Quick sample:

```
<?php
$range = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('2015-01-01'),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    new DateTime('2015-01-31 23:59:59')
);

foreach($range as $dateTime) {
    print $dateTime->format('d M Y') . '<br>';
}
```

**P1D** in DateInterval means - **P**eriod **1** **Day**

The reason for *23:59:59* in second datetime object is that if you want to include your last date in your date-range you have to at least add 1 second to your object.

Hope you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you're using the same object instead of instancing a new one.

Just call a new instance in every iteration:

```
$dayIterator = new DateTime(/* --- */);
```